# Python Pysftp Error

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

My code:

```
import pysftp 
s = pysftp.Connection(host='test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password') 
data = s.listdir() 
s.close() 
for i in data: 
    print i
```

I'm getting an error trying to connect to a SFTP server using pysftp.

This should be straight forward enough but I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gavinhinfey/Documents/Python Files/sftp_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    s = pysftp.Connection(host='test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pysftp.py", line 55, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-intel/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 303, in __init__
paramiko.SSHException: Unable to connect to test.rebex.net: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
Exception AttributeError: "'Connection' object has no attribute '_tranport_live'" in <bound     method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x101a5a810>> ignored
```

I've tried using different versions of python (mostly 2.7), I have all dependencies installed and I tried numerous sftp connections.
I'm using OS X 10.9.1.

Comment: sorry the code input code is `import pysftp

s = pysftp.Connection(host='test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password')
data = s.listdir()
s.close()
for i in data:
    print i`

Comment: are you sure your host is correct and your ports aren't blocked? your error log is telling you that your connection to host timed out, after which the `s` object is not initiated and throws normal errors for an object that failed to initiate.

Comment: I can connect with File Zilla with the same details? Does this mean that my ports are not blocked?

Comment: Strange.  Maybe try `log=True` in your `kwargs` for `Connection` and post what you get there.

Comment: Sorry but when I add log=True where does it output the log? Thanks

Comment: When you use File Zilla, which protocol are you using? FTP, FTPS, or SFTP?

Comment: I just tried using pythons builtin ftplib and it works. It appears to be FTP not SFTP that I needed. My apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That initial error appears to be a problem connecting with the remote server (SSHException).  The second (AttributeError), is from a bug in the code that occurs when the connection fails.  It is fixed in the latest version of pysftp

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp

```
pip install -U pysftp
```

is your friend.

Comment: Python 2.7's pip says: `no such option: -u`.

Answer (score 15):

updating the package didn't work for me, as it was already up-to-date (latest for python 2.7 at least)

Found a better aproach [here](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/issues/97/pysftp-029-breaks-builds).

1) You can manualy add the ssh key to the known_hosts file

```
ssh test.rebex.net
```

2) Or you can set a flag to ignore it

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None    # disable host key checking.
with pysftp.Connection('host', username='me',private_key=private_key,
                           private_key_pass=private_key_password,
                           cnopts=cnopts) as sftp
    # do stuff here
```

Comment: Never use the option 2), unless you do not care about security!

Answer (score 0):

@Martin.Prikryl: setting hostkeys = None is very useful in the initial stage of coding with pysftp.  Debugging a program that keeps failing for a known exception hides other problems that need attention--like making an actual connection.  I can deal with the 'man in the middle' problem later once I know my code is actually working correctly.

@All: The current pysftp.CnOpts() object appears to have a bug:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
```

The above code does not prevent host key checking.

python getfile_v3.py --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getfile_v3.py", line 9, in 
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
File "c:\Program Files\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pysftp_*init*_.py", line 64, in **init**
raise HostKeysException('No Host Keys Found')
pysftp.exceptions.HostKeysException: No Host Keys Found

The second line doesn't get executed because the first does the host key check by default.  If I set the key with:

```
      cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(hostkeys=None)
```

the same error results.

It appears that 'hostkeys' has been deprecated, and there is no way to disable the host key check.

Joe White

Comment: This answer is not answering the original question. Maybe try to do a bug report or ask another question?

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** for `SSHException: No hostkey for host test.rebex.net found`

**just to add it manually via ssh**

1. `ssh demo@test.rebex.net`
2. it will ask for password, you need to enter "password"
3. it will show you the message

```
The authenticity of host 'test.rebex.net (ip-adress)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:OzvpQxxxV9F/ECMXbQ7B7zbKxxxxUno65c.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

4. confirm action -> type "yes"
5. done, you will get a message, since now your sftp connection to 'test.rebex.net' should work

`Warning: Permanently added 'test.rebex.net,ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.`