# Verify host key with pysftp

Tags: python, ssh, public-key, pysftp

I am writing a program using pysftp, and it wants to verify the SSH host Key against `C:\Users\JohnCalvin\.ssh\known_hosts`.

Using PuTTY, the terminal program is saving it to the Registry `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys]`.

How do I reconcile the difference between pysftp and PuTTY?

My code is:

```py
import pysftp as sftp

def push_file_to_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='138.99.99.129', username='root', password='*********')
    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()

push_file_to_server()
```

The error response I am receiving is:

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py:61:
UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\JohnCalvin\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
 warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "E:\OneDrive\Python\GIT\DigitalCloud\pysftp_tutorial.py", line 14, in <module>
    push_file_to_server()
  File "E:\OneDrive\Python\GIT\DigitalCloud\pysftp_tutorial.py", line 7, in push_file_to_server
    s = sftp.Connection(host='138.99.99.129', username='root', password='********') 
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)   
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host) paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host 138.99.99.129 found.
Exception ignored in: <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x00000222FF3A6BE0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
    self.close()  
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 784, in close
    if self._sftp_live:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'
```

Comment: You can find the answer for your problem in [`pysftp`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp) [documentation](http://pysftp.readthedocs.io/) which mentions this issue explicitly [here](http://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-cnopts).

Answer (score 150):

*The pysftp has some bugs regarding host key handling, as described below. It also seems that the pysftp project was abandoned. Consider using Paramiko directly instead. The pysftp is just a wrapper on top of Paramiko and it does not add anything really significant. See  [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.

*For handling of host keys in Paramiko, see:

[Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*

---

*If you want to keep using pysftp, do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None` (as the second most upvoted answer shows), unless you do not care about security. You lose a protection against [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so.*

Use `CnOpts.hostkeys` (returns [`HostKeys`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/hostkeys.html)) to manage trusted host keys.

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='known_hosts')

with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

where the `known_hosts` contains a server public key(s) in a format like:

```
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQAB...
```

---

If you do not want to use an external file, you can also use

```
from base64 import decodebytes
# ...

keydata = b"""AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQAB..."""
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add('example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)

with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

Though as of pysftp 0.2.9, this approach will issue a warning, what seems like a bug:
["Failed to load HostKeys" warning while connecting to SFTP server with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56521549/850848)

---

An easy way to retrieve the host key in the needed format is using OpenSSH [`ssh-keyscan`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan):

```
$ ssh-keyscan example.com
# example.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQAB...
```

*(due to a bug in pysftp, this [does not work, if the server uses non-standard port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64438184/850848#64439662) – the entry starts with `[example.com]:port` + beware of [redirecting `ssh-keyscan` to a file in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64668279/850848))*

You can also make the application do the same automatically:
[Use Paramiko AutoAddPolicy with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53666106/850848)
(It will automatically add host keys of new hosts to `known_hosts`, but for known host keys, it will not accept a changed key)

---

Though for an absolute security, you should not retrieve the host key remotely, as you cannot be sure, if you are not being attacked already.

See my article [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)
It's for my WinSCP SFTP client, but most information there is valid in general.

---

If you need to verify the host key using its fingerprint only, see [Python - pysftp / paramiko - Verify host key using its fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46814823/850848).

Comment: what should i use for the `hostname` param in `cnopts.hostkeys.add()` when it appears in `known_hosts` like `|1|xyzxyzxyz=|abcabcabc=`?

Comment: @marengaz Use tha hostname, which you use in `pysftp.Connection`.

Answer (score 107):

One option is to disable the host key requirement:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   
with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)
```

You can find more info about that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38355117/1060738

**Important note:**

By setting `cnopts.hostkeys=None` you'll lose the protection against Man-in-the-middle attacks by doing so. Use @martin-prikryl answer to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, this is how I eventually resolved my problem.  But doing it this way only ignores the Host Key.  I would like to be able to retain the security (if possible) by reading the actual key.

Comment: A quick note. CnOpts() will fail if you have an empty known_hosts file in path.

Comment: See [my answer for a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43389508/850848).

Answer (score 21):

Try to use the 0.2.8 version of pysftp library. 

`$ pip uninstall pysftp && pip install pysftp==0.2.8`

And try with this:

```
try:
    ftp = pysftp.Connection(host, username=user, password=password)
 except:
    print("Couldn't connect to ftp")
    return False
```

Why this? 
Basically is a bug with the 0.2.9 of pysftp 
here all details
https://github.com/Yenthe666/auto_backup/issues/47

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I went through the link and didn't actually find any decent explanation why downgrading would help. While your statement *"here all details"* suggests that there should be some.

Answer (score 11):

Cook book to use different ways of pysftp.CnOpts() and hostkeys options.

Source : https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html

Host Key checking is enabled by default. It will use ~/.ssh/known_hosts by default. If you wish to disable host key checking (NOT ADVISED) you will need to modify the default CnOpts and set the .hostkeys to None.

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection('host', username='me', password='pass', cnopts=cnopts):
    # do stuff here
```

To use a completely different known_hosts file, you can override CnOpts looking for ~/.ssh/known_hosts by specifying the file when instantiating.

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='path/to/your/knownhostsfile')

with pysftp.Connection('host', username='me', password='pass', cnopts=cnopts):
    # do stuff here
```

If you wish to use ~/.ssh/known_hosts but add additional known host keys you can merge with update additional known_host format files by using .load method.

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.load('path/to/your/extra_knownhosts')
with pysftp.Connection('host', username='me', password='pass', cnopts=cnopts):
    # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 5):

If You try to connect by pysftp to "normal" FTP You have to set hostkey to None.

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None 
with pysftp.Connection(host='****',username='****',password='***',port=22,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print('DO SOMETHING')
```

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the server first with a Windows ssh client that uses the known_hosts file.
PuTTy stores the data in the windows registry,however OpenSSH uses the known_hosts file, and will add entries in there after you connect.
Default location for the file is %USERPROFILE%.ssh. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented `auto_add_key` in my [pysftp github fork](https://github.com/Fabian1337/pysftp).

`auto_add_key` will add the key to `known_hosts` if `auto_add_key=True`
Once a key is present for a host in `known_hosts` this key will be checked.

Please reffer [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) -> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43389508/10513304) about security concerns.

> Though for an absolute security, you should not retrieve the host key remotely, as you cannot be sure, if you are not being attacked already.

```
import pysftp as sftp

def push_file_to_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='138.99.99.129', username='root', password='pass', auto_add_key=True)
    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()

push_file_to_server()
```

Note: [Why using context manager](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-sinister-why-using-a-context-manager-is-a-better-choice-55ccfcecddb8)

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection(host, username="whatever", password="whatever", auto_add_key=True) as sftp:
    #do your stuff here
#connection closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi We sort of had the same problem if I understand you well. So check what pysftp version you're using. If it's the latest one which is 0.2.9 downgrade to 0.2.8.
Check this out. https://github.com/Yenthe666/auto_backup/issues/47

Comment: Do not suggest people to bypass a security feature, without explaining the consequences! You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Answer (score -1):

FWIR, if authentication is only username & pw, add remote server ip address to known_hosts like `ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.162 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` for ref https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-add-an-ssh-fingerprint-to-your-knownhosts-file-in-linux/