# Using Python's pysftp, how do you verify a host key?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, pysftp

I am using Python 2.7 pysftp package to connect to an SFTP server.

```
import pysftp

DOWNLOAD = {
"USERNAME": "username",
"PASSWORD": "password"
}

FTP_SITE = 'sftp.mysite.com'

srv = pysftp.Connection(host=FTP_SITE, username=DOWNLOAD['USERNAME'], 
                    password=DOWNLOAD['PASSWORD']
```

When I run the code above I get the error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSHException                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-205bb7b4b59b> in <module>()
      5 
      6 srv = pysftp.Connection(host=FTP_SITE, username=DOWNLOAD['USERNAME'], 
----> 7                         password=DOWNLOAD['PASSWORD'])

C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.pyc in __init__(self, host, username, private_key, password, port, private_key_pass, ciphers, log, cnopts, default_path)
    130         # check that we have a hostkey to verify
    131         if self._cnopts.hostkeys is not None:
--> 132             self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
    133 
    134         self._sftp_live = False

C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.pyc in get_hostkey(self, host)
     69         kval = self.hostkeys.lookup(host)  # None|{keytype: PKey}
     70         if kval is None:
---> 71             raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host) 
     72         # return the pkey from the dict
     73         return list(kval.values())[0]

SSHException: No hostkey for host sftp.mysite.com found.
```

I have the current work around of turning off the checking of host keys by doing the following:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None 
srv = pysftp.Connection(host=FTP_SITE, username=DOWNLOAD['USERNAME'], 
                         password=DOWNLOAD['PASSWORD'], cnopts=cnopts)
```

I would like to keep the security feature of the host key. Can anyone provide a link on how to generate the host keys, or provide a small sample of code here? I haven't been able to find much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.load('sftpserver.pub')
```

where the `sftpserver.pub` contains a server public key in a format like:

```
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQAB...
```

An easy way to retrieve the host key in this format is using OpenSSH [`ssh-keyscan`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan):

```
ssh-keyscan example.com
```

Though for absolute security, you should not retrieve the host key remotely, as you cannot be sure, if you are not being attacked already.

See my article [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey) It's for my WinSCP SFTP client, but most information there is valid in general.

---

If you do not want to use an external file, you can also use

```
cnopts.hostkeys.add(...)
```

---

For other options, see: [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).

---

*Though pysftp is dead. Better use Paramiko: [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*