# Use Paramiko AutoAddPolicy with pysftp

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, pysftp

This code is not working:

```
def sftp_connection(self):
    import pysftp
    connection = pysftp.Connection(self.host, username=self.system_name,
                  private_key=os.path.join(HOME, '.ssh', 'id_rsa'))

    # in the next lines I try to use AutoAddPolicy
    client = connection.sftp_client()
    client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy)
    return connection
```

This is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u/src/myapp-glo/myapp_doxis_archiv/tests/test_doxis_archiv.py", line 85, in test_beleg_to_archiv__ftpservercontext
    info_dict = beleg_to_archiv(beleg, self.archiv_belegart)
  File "/home/u/src/myapp-glo/myapp_doxis_archiv/beleg_to_archiv.py", line 28, in beleg_to_archiv
    transfer_log=send_data_via_ftp(temp_directory, archiv_belegart.doxis_archiv)
  File "/home/u/src/myapp-glo/myapp_doxis_archiv/beleg_to_archiv.py", line 71, in send_data_via_ftp
    with doxis_archiv.sftp_connection() as sftp:
  File "/home/u/src/myapp-glo/myapp_doxis_archiv/models.py", line 43, in sftp_connection
    private_key=os.path.join(HOME, '.ssh', 'id_rsa'))
  File "/home/u/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "/home/u/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
SSHException: No hostkey for host localhost found.
```

I get the exception before I try to set the `host_key_policy`.

I could not find a different way to access the client instance via pysftp.

Is there a way to set [`AutoAddPolicy`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy) before I get the exception?

There is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp). My question is about how to apply one of the several solutions which are provided in the old question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

pysftp does not use Paramiko [`SSHClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html) at all, it uses more low-level [`Transport` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html). So it does not have the [`MissingHostKeyPolicy`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.MissingHostKeyPolicy) functionality of `SSHClient`.

You would have to implement it on your own.

One possible implementation can be:

```
host = 'example.com'

# Loads .ssh/known_hosts    
cnopts = CnOpts()

hostkeys = None

if cnopts.hostkeys.lookup(host) == None:
    print("New host - will accept any host key")
    # Backup loaded .ssh/known_hosts file
    hostkeys = cnopts.hostkeys
    # And do not verify host key of the new host
    cnopts.hostkeys = None

with Connection(host, username=user, private_key=pkey, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    if hostkeys != None:
        print("Connected to new host, caching its hostkey")
        hostkeys.add(
            host, sftp.remote_server_key.get_name(), sftp.remote_server_key)
        hostkeys.save(pysftp.helpers.known_hosts())
```

Though, due to a bug in pysftp, this still might not work satisfactory. I suggest you switch to Paramiko altogether. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

Comment: `cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()` will [fail](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py?at=master#lines-64) on the first run if `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented `auto_add_key` in my [pysftp github fork](https://github.com/Fabian1337/pysftp).

`auto_add_key` will add the key to `known_hosts` if `auto_add_key=True`
Once a key is present for a host in `known_hosts` this key will be checked.

Please reffer [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) -> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43389508/10513304) about security concerns.

> Though for an absolute security, you should not retrieve the host key remotely, as you cannot be sure, if you are not being attacked already.

```
import pysftp as sftp

def push_file_to_server():
    s = sftp.Connection(host='138.99.99.129', username='root', password='pass', auto_add_key=True)
    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()

push_file_to_server()
```