# Generate private key for AWS Python Lambda to sftp into target host

Tags: python, aws-lambda, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am creating a Python AWS Lambda function that connects to db to extract data as CSV then sftp that CSV into an SFTP server (abc.example.com). I am using pysftp and Paramiko. Looks like pysftp needs a private key file for password less connection to SFTP host. How do I get this private key file?

Do we need to create a public/private key pair (`ssh-keygen`) at destination SFTP host? And then use the public part of that key within Lambda function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you don't have it already then you have to create keys using `ssh-keygen` on sftp host and use it.

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', private_key='/path/to/keyfile') as sftp:
    #
    # ... do sftp operations
    #
```

Reference: https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/cookbook.html

Comment: I have generated key pair at SFTP server (abc.example.com , this is an ec2) under the user u1009697. It creates 2 files. id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Now I took the id_rsa.pub file and used into lambda function - ```with pysftp.Connection(abc.example.com, username=u1009697, private_key=id_rsa.pub, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp: logger.debug("SFTP object created") ``` but it says SSH Error:not a valid DSA private key file

Comment: You have to use id_rsa not id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a public key authentication the same way you would do it for a normal (GUI/commandline) SFTP or SSH client. There's nothing pysftp/Python/Lambda-specific about that.

There are zillions of guide on the Internet showing how to do that.
For example my article [Set up SSH public key authentication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key).

---

And then use the private key in your Python/pysftp code:
[Connect to SFTP with key file using Python pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53875954/850848)

---

As pysftp requires the key in a physical file, what can be complicated to do in AWS Lambda, you can also hard-code the key in the Python code, if you switch to Paramiko:
[SSH/SCP through Paramiko with key in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43958696/850848)
(see [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848))

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have generated key pair at SFTP server (abc.example.com , this is an ec2) under the user u1009697. It creates 2 files. id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Now I took the id_rsa.pub file and used into lambda function - ```with pysftp.Connection(abc.example.com, username=u1009697, private_key=id_rsa.pub, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
          logger.debug("SFTP object created")``` but it says SSH Error:not a valid DSA private key file

Comment: 1) You should not generate the key pair on the server (though that's not your main problem). 2) The main problem is that the `private_key`  parameter obviously takes the private key (`id_rsa`), not the public key (`id_rsa.pub`). 3) The public key has to go to the `authorized_keys` file. – Please follow the instructions I have linked in my answer. First try to setup the authentication with some GUI/commandline SFTP/SSH client. And only then try to code the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin for your guidance, I am all set now !!