# sftp to aws lightsail python using pysftp key error

Tags: python, format, pem, pysftp

I have aws ssh key as awskey.pem.
I am trying to sftp to the host with pysftp.

```
import pysftp as sftp

keyfile='c:\\awskey.pem'
Cnopts=sftp.CnOpts()
Cnopts.hostkeys.load(keyfile)
srv=sftp.connection(host ='xx.xx.xx.xx',cnopts=Cnopts)
lpath='c:\\test.txt'
rpath='test.txt'
srv.put(lpath,rpath)
srv.close()
```

there seems to be a problem reading the pem file
as i get the error 
'pysftp.exceptions.HostKeysException: Host keys not found'
In searching other sites there is no discussion on 
the format of a key file.
Not sure if it is supposed to be a .pem
format or I have to convert it to some other format.
After spending 2 days on this I am no further ahead.

```
keyfile='c:\\awskey.pem'     
srv=sftp.connection(host ='xx.xx.xx.xx',username='user',private_key=keyfile)
```

and now i get error
pysftp.exceptions.HostKeysException: No Host Keys Found
Must be missing something somewhere.
This is on Windows 10 so no .ssh/known_hosts file.
Do I need to retrieve the host key ?
or switch back to  pysftp 0.2.8  as suggested elsewhere?

Comment: that is from Amazon web services  AWS has a
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA

Answer (score 1):

finally got it to work.
Installed ubuntu on win10.
Logged in to aws with ssh -i "key.pem" uname@aws 
which saved the known_hosts file.
Had to use ssh-keygen and key-scan from 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6533
to correct the file.
finally copy known_hosts from /root/.ssh to c:/user/myname/.ssh and
not from /home/.ssh/
so code is now

```
awshost="www.xxxxxxx.com"
keyfile=r'C:\files\docs\1-AWS\LightsailDefaultKey-us-west-2.pem'
known=r'C:\Users\myname\.ssh\known_hosts'
cn = sftp.CnOpts(knownhosts=known)

srv = sftp.Connection(host=awshost,
                username='bitnami',
                private_key=keyfile,
                cnopts=cn)
```

and it connects with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is regarding the server host key. For that see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).

Your problem has nothing to do with your private key, which you should use for authentication. The private key goes to `private_key` argument of [`Connection` constructor](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection).
See [Connect to SFTP with key file using Python pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53875954/850848)

---

See also *my* article about the [keys involved in SSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here are the steps I took to resolve:

1. Open a terminal and navigate to the folder containing the `.pem` file.
2. Run `chmod 400 keyfile.pem`
3. Use OpenSSH to ssh into your instance: `ssh -i "keyfile.pem" USERNAME@IP_OF_INSTANCE`

Now you can go back to running your python script.

**Explanation:**

pysftp searches for ssh key entries in 'known_hosts'. The first time you SSH into the instance, OpenSSH automatically creates an entry for it in 'known_hosts', which pysftp can now locate.

The reason for step 2 above is that AWS requires more restrictive permissions for the key file.

**Note for Windows users:**

If you try to use PuTTy to do this, pysftp won't be able to locate the SSH entries, as PuTTy stores them in the Windows **registry**. Instead, you can install and use OpenSSH on Windows, then in a bash terminal (such as Git BASH) you can follow the same 3 steps above.

Comment: Thanks very helpful will try that next week

Comment: finally got it to work.installed ubuntu on win10. logged in to aws with ssh -i "key.pem" uname@aws which saved the known_hosts file.Had to use ssh-keygen and key-scan from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6533

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it to work as Filezilla works with just the
key file,user,hostip then setting hostkeys to None
works fine after setting CnOpts call to the hostip.

```
import pysftp as sftp

hostip  = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
keyfile ='c:\\awskey.pem'
userb   = "bitnami"

Cnopts=sftp.CnOpts(hostip)
Cnopts.hostkeys = None

srv=sftp.connection(host = hostip,
                    username=userb,
                    cnopts=Cnopts)


lpath='c:\\test.txt'
rpath='apps/wordpress/htdocs/mytheme/test.txt'
srv.put(lpath,rpath)
srv.close()
```

Comment: You still miss the point. This is not a solution. By setting `Cnopts.hostkeys = None` you disable host key verification, what is a security flaw. It's not that *"Filezilla works"* like that. You can do this this any SFTP server, but it's wrong.