# Doing sftp using pysftp but getting hostkey error

Tags: rsa, python-3.7, ssh-keys, pysftp

Trying to connect to sftp server using ssh key

```
#!/bin/python

import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection(host='sftp.myserver.com', username='stg', private_key='/Users/joel/.ssh/id_rsa_sftp', private_key_pass='') as sftp:
```

And I am getting

```
raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
```

Comment: See [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848#43389508).

Comment: this is know issue with pysftp = 0.2.9 and so i moved to [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to load HostKeys" warning while connecting to SFTP server with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521549/failed-to-load-hostkeys-warning-while-connecting-to-sftp-server-with-pysftp)

Answer (score 0):

You could use my pysftp fork from [github](https://github.com/Fabian1337/pysftp) and add `auto_add_key=True`
This will add the host key on the first connection to your `known_hosts` file...

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret', auto_add_key=True) as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public'):             # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
        sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```