# How to check if a file exists in SFTP with pysftp?

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am working in an etl (first time), and I need to extract some files from the client's SFTP. The problem I have is that the files number is variable, so I need to check if the file exist and get it, the file format is like "file_**YYYY-MM-DD**-number-**n**" where `YYYY-MM-DD` is the current date and `n` is the number of the file, so if there are 7 files I have to look for:

- file_2019-08-25-number-1
- file_2019-08-25-number-2

Until now I have found that I can do something like this

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
with pysftp.Connection(host=host, port=port, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    files = sftp.listdir(directory)
```

How do I find in the files there?

Answer (score 9):

To check for an existence of a file with pysftp, use [`Connection.exists` method](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.exists):

```
with pysftp.Connection(...) as sftp:
    if sftp.exists("file_2019-08-25-number-1"):
        print("1 exists")
    if sftp.exists("file_2019-08-25-number-2"):
        print("2 exists")
```

---

*Though you better do not use pysftp in the first place, as it is a dead project. Use Paramiko instead (see [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)).*

*To check file existence with Paramiko, use [`SFTPClient.stat`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.stat). See [How to check if the created file using Paramiko exec_command exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70853265/850848)*.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expression module to determine if a filename matches the general pattern you're looking as the example below does.

```
import re


files = [
    'file_2019-08-25-number-1',
    'foo.bar',
    'file_2019-08-25-number-2',
    'file_2018-02-28-number-42',
    'some_other_file.txt'
]

pattern = re.compile(r'file_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-number-\d+')

for filename in files:
    if pattern.match(filename):
        print(f'{filename!r} matches pattern')
```

Output:

```
'file_2019-08-25-number-11' matches pattern
'file_2019-08-25-number-2' matches pattern
'file_2018-02-28-number-42' matches pattern
```

If all you want to do is check for a specific filename, you could do something like this:

```
if filename.startswith('file_2019-08-25-number-'):
    # Do something with filename.
    ...
```