# With pysftp, how can I specify a timeout value for the connection?

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

With pysftp, I see how to set a timeout for any commands once you're already connected, but I don't see how to set a timeout for the connection itself. I feel like I'm missing something somewhere. Just to try it, I tried adding `timeout=3` to the `Connection` method and got an error, and tried using `cnopts.timeout=3` and that did nothing at all. For the record, I'm using Python 3 on Windows, if that affects anything.

Here's some simple test code you can experiment with, if it helps. (As is, the connection times out after about 30 seconds.)

```
import pysftp

print("\n"*25)
cnopts=pysftp.CnOpts()
# - I know this next line is insecure, it's just for this test program.
cnopts.hostkeys = None

print('Connecting...')
# - 8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS server. It doesn't respond to sftp requests at all,
# - so it's a good test case for how long a connection timeout takes.
with pysftp.Connection('8.8.8.8', username='anonymous', password='password',
                    cnopts=cnopts) as SFTP:
    print("Wait, how did you get this far?")
print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 5):

It does not look like that pysftp allows setting a connection timeout.

You can use Paramiko directly instead ([pysftp is just a wrapper around Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)).

[Paramiko `SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) method has `timeout` parameter.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password, timeout=timeout)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

Comment: Dang. I saw the same, but was hoping there was a way around that that I missed somewhere. Hmm, I suppose I'll go put in a feature request for pysftp in the meantime. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with:

```
Connection.timeout (35000)
```

Comment: But you can call that only after you create the `Connection`, so only after you connect. So does this allow you to set the *connection* timeout?