# Python moving file on SFTP server to another folder

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I wrote this script to save a file from an SFTP remote folder to a local folder. It then removes the file from the SFTP. I want to change it so it stops removing files and instead saves them to a backup folder on the SFTP. How do I do that in pysftp? I cant find any documentation regarding it...

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

myHostname = "123"
myUsername = "456"
myPassword = "789"

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password="789", cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.cwd("/Production/In/")
    directory_structure = sftp.listdir_attr()
    local_dir= "D:/"
    remote_dir = "/Production/"
    remote_backup_dir = "/Production/Backup/"

    for attr in directory_structure:
        if attr.filename.endswith(".xml"):
            file = attr.filename
            sftp.get(remote_dir + file, local_dir + file)
            print("Moved " + file + " to " + local_dir)
            sftp.remove(remote_dir + file)
```

Don't worry about my no hostkey or the password in plain. I'm not keeping it that way once i get the script working :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Connection.rename`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.rename):

```
sftp.rename(remote_dir + file, remote_backup_dir + file)
```

---

*Obligatory warnings:*

- *Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.
- *Do not use pysftp. It's dead. Use Paramiko. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.