# pysftp: How to update last modified date

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to move a certain file to another directory after doing some process over it.

Moving the file was easy using [Connection.rename](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.rename)

```
import pysftp
conn = pysftp.Connection(host = 'host', username = 'user', password = 'password')
remote_src = '/dir1/file1.csv'
remote_dest = '/dir2/archive_file1.csv'
conn.rename(remote_src, remote_dest)
conn.close()
```

But the *LastModified* date remains same as of original file.
Is there a way to update the *LastModified* date to current date while renaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @MartinPrikryl I was able to finally achieve my purpose.

[pysftp.Connection](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection) has a property [sftp_client](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-sftp-client) which as per documentation returns the active [paramiko.SFTPClient](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient) object.
I used this property to call [paramiko.SFTPClient.utime](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.utime)

```
import pysftp
conn = pysftp.Connection(host = 'host', username = 'user', password = 'password')
remote_src = '/dir1/file1.csv'
remote_dest = '/dir2/archive_file1.csv'
conn.rename(remote_src, remote_dest)
# below is the line I added after renaming the file
conn.sftp_client.utime(remote_dest, None)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename (move) of a file does not change the file's modification time. It changes modification time of the folder.

If you want to change modification time of the file, you have to do it explicitly. pysftp does not have an API for that. But you can use Paramiko [`SFTPClient.utime`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.utime). See also [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

Comment: Thanks @Martin for your reply. It helped me a lot.