# pysftp throwing paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException even though known_hosts file provided?

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

Getting error

> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host target.org found.

when using `pysftp` (for a connection that requires a specific port), even though I am providing the same known_hosts file that was initially used to connect to that location (following the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43389508/8236733)). Ie. did...

```
[airflow@airflowetl reporting]$ sftp -oPort=15259 my_user@target.org
The authenticity of host '[target.org]:15259 ([205.172.2.88]:15259)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:UM6OflG0rkcYohes7qOlYoJZ4TIqVd0JQSh7HXYZQVA.
RSA key fingerprint is MD5:33:c2:30:22:57:5b:57:98:2f:11:07:4d:a3:4a:10:0f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[target.org]:15259,[205.172.2.88]:15259' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
password
Enter password for my_user
Password:
Connected to target.org.
sftp> ls
csv_drop        test_results    
sftp> exit
```

and then copied the `/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts` to another location

```bash
[airflow@airflowetl .ssh]$ ls -lha
total 8.0K
drwx------   2 airflow airflows   25 Oct 19 17:31 .
drwx------. 32 airflow airflows 4.0K Oct 19 17:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 airflow airflows  777 Oct 19 17:32 known_hosts
[airflow@airflowetl .ssh]$ ls -lha /home/airflow/projects/backups/reporting/configs/known_hosts 
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflows 777 Oct 19 17:34 /home/airflow/projects/backups/reporting/configs/known_hosts
```

(noting that the permissions are the name for the original and copy) that gets used like...

```py
# connect to ftp location
assert os.path.isfile(os.path.join(PROJECT_HOME, "configs", "known_hosts"))
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts=os.path.join(PROJECT_HOME, "configs", "known_hosts"))
#cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts="/home/airflow/.ssh/known_hosts")
HOSTNAME = "target.org"
PORT = 15259
sftp = pysftp.Connection(HOSTNAME,
                         port=PORT,
                         username=CREDS["sink"]["ftp_creds"]["username"],
                         password=CREDS["sink"]["ftp_creds"]["password"],
                         cnopts=cnopts)
print(sftp.pwd())
print(sftp.listdir())

sftp.cwd(CONF["reporting_configs"]["to"]["share_folder_path"])
print(sftp.pwd())
print(sftp.listdir())
```

Yet, when running the script I get the error saying it could not find the hostkey (Note that even using the original known_hosts file path throws the same error (and happens whether using hostname or the IP)). What could be causing this? Any more debugging steps I could try to get more info? Don't have much experience with this kind of thing.

Looking in the debugger while running, I see that the cnopts hostkeys entries does seem to contain the right hostkey...

```
<HostKeyEntry ['[target.org]:15259', '[205.172.2.88]:15259']: <paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey object at 0x7f8d752d4208>>
```

Note that the hostkey entry is **'[target.org]:15259' (ie. it is combining the specified port), even though the name provided as the service name to the connection function is just 'target.org'**

The full traceback looks like...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./source/local2ftp.2.py", line 52, in <module>
    cnopts=cnopts)
  File "/home/airflow/projects/backups/reporting/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "/home/airflow/projects/backups/reporting/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host target.org found.
Exception ignored in: <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7f1a61df6f98>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/projects/backups/reporting/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/home/airflow/projects/backups/reporting/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 784, in close
    if self._sftp_live:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'
```

Note that the user I used to initially connect via `sftp` in the command line and am using in the `pysftp` script is not the user running the script (the user I used to connect to the sftp server is a special set of credentials for connecting). I don't know if this is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**: The code expects the `pystfp.Connection` hostname to match that in the hostkey file (eg. `~/.ssh/known_hosts`), but if the rsa entry in the **hostkey file entry was created with a connection that specified the port and thus caused the rsa entry in known_hosts to be formatted in a way that `pysftp` could not understand / handle**,

like...

```
[airflow@airflowetl reporting]$ sftp -oPort=15259 my_user@target.org
```

The rsa entry that gets created looks like...

```
'[target.org]:15259,[205.172.2.88]:15259 ssh-rsa AAAAB3HJGVJGCTCKHGVYTVKUH===...'
```

so when you use this hostkey file for the `knownhosts` in...

```py
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts=os.path.join(path, to, hostkey, or, known_hosts, file))
hostname = "target.org"
port = 15259
sftp = pysftp.Connection(hostname, port, username=user, password=pass, cnopts=cnopts)
```

the code ends up checking the hostkey file for an entry that looks like

```
"target.org"
```

(what you entered as the `hostname`) but only finds

```
"[target.org]:15259"
```

(the entry in the hostkey / known_hosts file formatted for the specific port you connected on) so throws an error.

Note also that you can't just use *"[target.org]:15259"* as the `hostname` for the `pysftp.Connection()` function either just to get it to match when the `pysftp` code does this internal check because it will say that it does not recognize the service name since (apparently) that's not a valid servicename representation (ie. it won't just know to separate that string into the `hostname` and `port` components).

**What I had to do was...**

- Copy the known_hosts file that was created when I initially connected to the target.org host
- then in that file, manually edit it to look like

```
'target.org,205.172.2.88 ssh-rsa AAAAB3HJGVJGCTCKHGVYTVKUH===...'
```

---

Specifically in the code, the `pysftp.Connection()` function...

1. Tries to [get the hostkey](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-131)
2. and uses the underlying `Paraminko` module to try to [find the hostkey entry](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/hostkeys.py#L190) from the `knownhosts` file given in the `cnopt` arg
3. which uses the function [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/hostkeys.py#L197) to match the string *literal* entries from the hostkey file with the `hostname` that you entered as the `pysftp.Connection` arg (which, if you connected to using a specific port, created an rsa entry that when taken as a literal is not formatted the way you likely are passing in the `hostname` arg and is not even a valid host name), thus confusing the matching logic and causing it to not find any matches
4. thus causing an exception to be raised, [here](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-71) back in the `pysftp` code

Answer (score 4):

The pysftp does not support the host key entries with the port.

- Either skip pysftp and use Paramiko directly. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).
- Or hack it by replacing the `[target.org]:15259` with `target.org` in the `known_hosts` file.

Comment: Yes, ended up figuring this out after digging into the internals of the code, but thank you for confirming that I was not just using the module wrong or something like that. Ended up doing the hack solution / workaround.