# "'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'" when pysftp connection fails

Tags: python, exception, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'd like to catch nicely the error when *"No hostkey for host *** is found"* and give an appropriate message to the end user. I tried this:

```
import pysftp, paramiko
try: 
    with pysftp.Connection('1.2.3.4', username='root', password='') as sftp:
        sftp.listdir()
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
    print('SSH error, you need to add the public key of your remote in your local known_hosts file first.', e)
```

but unfortunately the output is not very nice:

```
SSH error, you need to add the public key of your remote in your local known_hosts file first. No hostkey for host 1.2.3.4 found.
Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x00000000036B6D38>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 784, in close
    if self._sftp_live:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'
```

**How to nicely avoid these last lines / this "exception ignored" with a `try: except:`?**

Comment: As of 2022, the pysftp seems to be an abandoned project. I suggest you switch to Paramiko. The pysftp is just a wrapper around Paramiko. So if you have pysftp, you have Paramiko too.  See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The analysis by @reverse_engineer is correct. However:

1. It seems that an additional attribute, `self._transport`, also is defined too late.
2. The problem *can* be temporarily corrected until a permanent fix comes by subclassing the `pysftp.Connection` class as follows:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko


class My_Connection(pysftp.Connection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._sftp_live = False
        self._transport = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

try: 
    with My_Connection('1.2.3.4', username='root', password='') as sftp:
        l = sftp.listdir()
        print(l)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
    print('SSH error, you need to add the public key of your remote in your local known_hosts file first.', e)
```

**Update**

I could not duplicate this error on my desktop. However, I see in the source for `pysftp` in the code where it initializes its `_cnopts` attribute with `self._cnopts = cnopts or CnOpts()` where `cnopts` is a keyword parameter to the `pysftp.Connection` constructor and there is a possibilty of the `CnOpts` constructor throwing a `HostKeysException` exception if no host keys are found resulting in the `_cnopts` attribute not being set.

Try the following updated code and let me know if it works:

```py
import pysftp
import paramiko

class My_Connection(pysftp.Connection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if kwargs.get('cnopts') is None:
                kwargs['cnopts'] = pysftp.CnOpts()
        except pysftp.HostKeysException as e:
            self._init_error = True
            raise paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException(str(e))
        else:
            self._init_error = False

        self._sftp_live = False
        self._transport = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._init_error:
            self.close()

try:
    with My_Connection('1.2.3.4', username='root', password='') as sftp:
        l = sftp.listdir()
        print(l)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
    print('SSH error, you need to add the public key of your remote in your local known_hosts file first.', e)
```

Comment: Nicely found, though these kind of fixes can be a bit risky since in the end you change the behavior of the constructor, but I suspects this works without side-effects

Comment: I tried the above code with my credentials but getting the below error 

>>> AttributeError: 'MyConnection' object has no attribute '_cnopts'

Comment: @Karpi If that doesn't resolve your issue, open a new question and add a comment directed to me so that I know you have done so. But be sure to post a *full* stacktrace.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. I solved this by disabling the hostkeys in the cnops:

```
import pysftp as sftp

FTP_HOST = "sftp.abcd.com"
FTP_USER = "root"
FTP_PASS = ""

cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with sftp.Connection(host=FTP_HOST, username=FTP_USER, password=FTP_PASS, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
   print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
   sftp.cwd('/folder/')  # Switch to a remote directory
   directory_structure = sftp.listdir_attr() # Obtain structure of the remote directory

for attr in directory_structure:
   print(attr.filename, attr)
```

Comment: Disabling host key checking is a security flaw. You lose a protection against MITM attacks. Do not do that!

Answer (score 12):

I think that's a bug in pysftp. You will always have that behavior when `pysftp.Connection` fails on a `No hostkey for XXX found` exception, because the failed `Connection` object (it fails so you can't access it, but it exists in the Python interpreter) gets cleaned up by the GC, which deletes it, and as you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-1013), that tries to close the connection first.

We see that `close()` [checks whether the connection is live](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-784) by checking `self._sftp_live`. However, the Exception was thrown in the constructor of `Connection` before that attribute is defined (the exception happens [line 132](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-132), while `_sftp_live` is defined [line 134](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-134)), so that leaves the failed `Connection` object in an inconsistent state and hence the uncaught exception you see.

This has no easy solution that I can think of except introducing a nice bug fix to the pysftp project ;)

Comment: I believe this bug still exists for anyone coming to this answer in Sept 2021 - just got burned by this badly. When you hit this in *durasftp*, since on closure it tries to reconnect, you will see this log *millions of times*.

Comment: i still do have the same problem using pysftp 0.2.9