# how to download file from sftp to blob with username, passphrase, and key with python

Tags: python

How do you download a file from an sftp server to a blob with username, passphrase, and key in python?

I found this example but I also need to include a passphrase and download it to an azure blob.

```
    import pysftp
    host = 'test.rebex.net'
    port = 22
    username = 'demo'
    password= 'password'
    try:
    conn = pysftp.Connection(host=host,port=port,username=username, password=password)
    print("connection established successfully")
    except:
    print('failed to establish connection to targeted server')

    current_dir = conn.pwd
    print('our current working directory is: ',current_dir)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["'Connection' object has no attribute '\_sftp\_live'" when pysftp connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002585/connection-object-has-no-attribute-sftp-live-when-pysftp-connection-fails)

Comment: How do you pass in the private key? How do you download a file to the Azure blob?