# Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented') error while connecting SFTP with Databricks

Tags: python, sftp, databricks, pysftp

I'm trying to connect to SFTP from a notebook with databricks in python. My notebook looks like this:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko

# set parameters
host_name = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' 
username = 'FTP_USERNAME' 
file_path_to_rsa_key = "/path/key_rsa" 
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts() 
cnopts.hostkeys = None

# connect to SFTP
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host_name, username=username, private_key=file_path_to_rsa_key, cnopts=cnopts)
data = sftp.listdir()
sftp.close()

# Prints out the directories and files, line by line
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

I have the following error:

`Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented')`

when running the following block:

```
try:
  conn = pysftp.Connection(host_name, username=username, private_key=file_path_to_rsa_key, cnopts=cnopts)
  print("connection established successfully")
except:
  print('failed to establish connection to targeted server')
```

It print `connection established successfully`

What does it mean? What should I do? Is the issue with `listdir()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is mostly because *pysftp*. I end up switching entirely to *paramiko* and everything is working fine. The SFTP server modified the login response and *pysftp* was too strict in the acceptable responses to take it without trouble. I noticed something similar when I tried to use a non-RSA private key that worked fine for ssh / sftp directly but not *pysftp*.

There is also some interesting information here [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434941/pysftp-vs-paramiko)