# Download new files only, ignoring file extensions, from remote SFTP server in Python

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

```
from datetime import datetime
import pysftp
import fnmatch
import os
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG

Hostname = "Hostname"
Username = "Username"
Password = "Password"
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=Hostname, username=Username, password=Password,
                       cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection successfully established ... ")

    local_dir = r"D:\testing"
    remote_dir = r'C:\Users\admin\Documents\personal'

    for entry in sftp.listdir(remote_dir):
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(entry)
        for entry1 in sftp.listdir(local_dir):
            root1, ext1 = os.path.splitext(entry1)
            if root == root1:
                if ext != ext1:
                    pass
            elif root != root1:
                remotepath = os.path.join(remote_dir, entry)
                localpath = os.path.join(local_dir, entry)
                sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime=False)
```

I'm trying to export files from SFTP server to local. In order to do that I need to compare files by filename and file extension from server and local folder.

For instance `abc.xlsx`, `abc.csv`, `adc.txt` from server and
local folder has got `abc.xlsx`, then my script shouldn't copy any files with same name and same extension or different extension.

Here I need to compare the filenames and extension

- if the same name then don't download
- if same name and different extension don't download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to use `os.listdir` for the local path.
- There's no need to re-read the local folder every time *(unless you somehow aim to cater for multiple files with same base name in the remote directory)*.
- Your code for identifying new files is not correct either.
- You should not use `os.path.join` for SFTP paths.

This should do:

```
localfiles = os.listdir(local_dir)
for rentry in sftp.listdir(remote_dir):
    rroot, rext = os.path.splitext(rentry)
    found = False
    for lentry in localfiles:
        lroot, lext = os.path.splitext(lentry)
        if rroot == lroot:
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        remotepath = remote_dir + "/" rentry
        localpath = os.path.join(local_dir, rentry)
        sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime=False)
```

---

*Though these days, you should not use pysftp, as it is dead. Use Paramiko directly instead. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848). The above code will work with Paramiko too with its [`SFTPClient.listdir`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir).*

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.

Comment: Wow, Martin, it worked like a charm, tons and millions of Thanks to you. I have modified entire script to be based on paramiko. 
Also I modified the localfiles initiation to after Found Flag initialization. Then It works exactly like I wanted..