# Upload zip file from Google cloud storage to SFTP server without loading into memory using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, sftp, pysftp

I want to upload large zip files from google cloud bucket to SFTP server without loading into memory and cloud function.
I am using pysftp for SFTP transfer.

```
with pysftp.Connection(host="SFTP Server", username='test', password='test', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.cwd("/tmp")
    sftp.put("zip_file_from_google_bucket")
```

Can we access os path of the file in the bucket and provide the file path in the `sftp.put()` since `gs://` path will not be recognised in the `sftp.put()`?

Do we have any other method to transfer?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First, better use Paramiko. The pysftp is dead. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848). In any case, the following will work both with Paramiko and pysftp.*

---

Combine [Paramiko `SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) with [GCS `Blob.download_to_file`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_download_to_file):

```
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project='myproject')
bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('archive.zip')

with sftp.open('/sftp/path/archive.zip', mode="w+", bufsize=32768) as f:
    blob.download_to_file(f)
```

---

Alternatively, combine [`SFTPClient.putfo`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.putfo) with [`Blob.open`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_open).

```
with blob.open("rb") as f:
    sftp.putfo(f, '/sftp/path/archive.zip')
```

---

*(untested, but it should give you the idea at least)*