# PYSFTP script to Upload and Download

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

I need some help I'm getting below message when i try to connect. The script Im executing is below. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue?

Also, once I get this issue fixed Im looking to add to this script the ability to listen until the result file is available and to download it from a different remote directory.

Thank you, in advance

```
No hostkey for host mysftpserver.com found.
Exception AttributeError: "'Connection' object has no attribute 
'_sftp_live'" in <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection 
object at 0x101d8cd50>> ignored

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Script

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftpExample():

    try:
        s = sftp.Connection(host='mysftpserver', port=1211, username='myusername', password='mypassword')

        remotepath='/Orders/incoming/myfile.csv'
        localpath='/Users/myusername/projects/order88.csv'
        s.put(localpath,remotepath)

        s.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

sftpExample()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [pysftp documentation](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/) and other answers on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp) also seem to suggest that the error can be resolved by setting `cnopts.hostkeys = None`.

So the full code would be something like:

```
import pysftp
def sftpExample():
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None  
    with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        sftp.put('/Users/myusername/projects/order88.csv','/Orders/incoming/myfile.csv')  # upload file to public/ on remote
        sftp.close()

sftpExample()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please do **NOT** use this answer. This removes identification security for SSH. Check the official documentation and use the `ssh` command or manually place the server's host key in your `~./ssh/known_hosts` file.

Comment: As it says at the official documentation [https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/][https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/] just keep it simple and try this (adapt it to your use of case):
```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public'):             # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
        sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [pysftp documentation](http://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-cnopts) you need to have the remote host key in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. You can do this by connecting to the server via the `ssh` command (it will ask you if you want to add a new key to your hosts file; simply type `yes` if you trust the remote host's fingerprint).

The official documentation also points out how to disable host checking entirely, but this is **NOT recommended** as it would defeat critical security features for SSH identification.

Comment: I did try it out but I would still get an error. I tried                                                                                                    
import pysftp as sftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None                                                                                 
 s = sftp.Connection(host=, port=, username=, password='', cnopts=cnopts)                       I get below error                                                                                     
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
NameError: name 'pysftp' is not defined

Comment: When you say `import pysftp as sftp`, you are importing the module under a different name. So you would then say `cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()`, because you changed the name on import!

Comment: I also edited my answer above if that helps... All of the other answers I've seen use `with pysftp.Connection(...)` instead of `s=pysftp.Connection(...)`, so that might be a factor as well!