# Python - pysftp / paramiko - Verify host key using its fingerprint

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, pysftp

This code throws an exception. How can I verify an SSH fingerprint without storing it in a file? I believe the code below is designed for a public key. But the client with the SFTP server validated the fingerprint and did not get me the public key.

```
import os
import shutil

import pysftp
import paramiko

connection_info = {
    'server': "example.com",
    'user': "user",
    'passwd': "password",
    'target_dir': "out/prod",
    'hostkey': "ssh-rsa 2048 d8:4e:f1:f1:f1:f1:f1:f1:21:31:41:14:13:12:11:aa",
}

def move_files_from_server_to_local(server, localpath):
    target_dir = server['target_dir']
    keydata = "d8:4e:f1:f1:f1:f1:f1:f1:21:31:41:14:13:12:11:aa"
    key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
    options = pysftp.CnOpts()
    options.hostkeys.add('example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)
    with pysftp.Connection(
                    server['server'],
                    username=server['user'],
                    password=server['passwd'],
                    cnopts=options) as conn:
        conn.get_d(target_dir, localpath)
        delete_files_from_dir(conn, target_dir)

move_files_from_server_to_local(connection_info, "/")
```

The code is based on [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp#43389508).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can use either of these two methods:

### In case you need to verify only one specific host key

Use [`ssh-keyscan`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan) (or similar) to retrieve the host public key:

```
ssh-keyscan example.com > tmp.pub
```

The `tmp.pub` will look like (`known_hosts` file format):

```
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0hVqZOvZ7yWgie9OHdTORJVI5fJJoH1yEGamAd5G3werH0z7e9ybtq1mGUeRkJtea7bzru0ISR0EZ9HIONoGYrDmI7S+BiwpDBUKjva4mAsvzzvsy6Ogy/apkxm6Kbcml8u4wjxaOw3NKzKqeBvR3pc+nQVA+SJUZq8D2XBRd4EDUFXeLzwqwen9G7gSLGB1hJkSuRtGRfOHbLUuCKNR8RV82i3JvlSnAwb3MwN0m3WGdlJA8J+5YAg4e6JgSKrsCObZK7W1R6iuyuH1zA+dtAHyDyYVHB4FnYZPL0hgz2PSb9c+iDEiFcT/lT4/dQ+kRW6DYn66lS8peS8zCJ9CSQ==
```

Now, you can calculate a fingerprint of that public key with [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen):

```
ssh-keygen -l -f tmp.pub -E md5
```

*(use the `-E md5` only with newer versions of OpenSSH that support multiple fingerprint algorithms and default to SHA256)*

You will get something like:

```
2048 MD5:c4:26:18:cf:a0:15:9a:5f:f3:bf:96:d8:3b:19:ef:7b example.com (RSA)
```

If the fingerprint matches with the one you have, you can now safely assume that the `tmp.pub` is a legitimate public key and use it in the code:

```
from base64 import decodebytes
# ...

keydata = b"""AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0hV..."""
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add('example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)

with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

*(based on [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848))*

### In case you need to automate verification of a host key based on its fingerprint

E.g. because the fingerprint comes from an external configuration.

I'm not sure if a limited API of pysftp allows that. You probably would have to skip pysftp and use [Paramiko library](https://www.paramiko.org/) directly (pysftp uses Paramiko internally).

With Paramiko, you can cleverly implement [`MissingHostKeyPolicy` interface](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.MissingHostKeyPolicy).

Start with how [`AutoAddPolicy`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy) is implemented:

```
class AutoAddPolicy (MissingHostKeyPolicy):
    """
    Policy for automatically adding the hostname and new host key to the
    local `.HostKeys` object, and saving it.  This is used by `.SSHClient`.
    """

    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        client._host_keys.add(hostname, key.get_name(), key)
        if client._host_keys_filename is not None:
            client.save_host_keys(client._host_keys_filename)
        client._log(DEBUG, 'Adding %s host key for %s: %s' %
                    (key.get_name(), hostname, hexlify(key.get_fingerprint())))
```

Note that in the code you have the fingerprint available in `hexlify(key.get_fingerprint())`. Just compare that value against the fingerprint you have. If it matches, just return. Otherwise raise an exception,
like the [`RejectPolicy`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.RejectPolicy) does.

---

Another solution (which would work even with pysftp) is to implement [`PKey`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#module-paramiko.pkey) in a way that it holds only the fingerprint. And implement its [`__eq__` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.__eq__) (or `__cmp__` before Paramiko 3.0) to compare the fingerprint only. Such an instance of `PKey` can then be added to `cnopts.hostkeys.add`.

*OP posted an implementation of this approach in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46814823/850848#46839480). Allegedly for Python 3, more complex implementation is needed, as seen in [Connecting to an SFTP server using pysftp and Python 3 with just the server fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47586224/850848)*.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Martin Prikryl's answer, below is my solution.

```
def trim_fingerprint(fingerprint):
    if fingerprint.startswith('ssh-rsa 2048 '):
        return fingerprint[len('ssh-rsa 2048 '):]
    return fingerprint
def clean_fingerprint(fingerprint):
    return trim_fingerprint(fingerprint).replace(':', '')

class FingerprintKey:
    def __init__(self, fingerprint):
        self.fingerprint = clean_fingerprint(fingerprint)
    def compare(self, other):
        if callable(getattr(other, "get_fingerprint", None)):
            return other.get_fingerprint() == self.fingerprint
        elif clean_fingerprint(other) == self.get_fingerprint():
            return True
        elif md5(other).digest().encode('hex') == self.fingerprint:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.compare(other)
    def get_fingerprint(self):
        return self.fingerprint
    def get_name(self):
        return u'ssh-rsa'
    def asbytes(self):
         # Note: This returns itself.
         #   That way when comparisons are done to asbytes return value,
         #   this class can handle the comparison.
        return self
```

usage:

```
options = pysftp.CnOpts()
options.hostkeys.clear()
options.hostkeys.add('www.example.com', u'ssh-rsa', FingerprintKey("ssh-rsa 2048 d8:4e:f1:f1:f1:f1:f1:f1:21:31:41:14:13:12:11:aa"))
    with pysftp.Connection(
                    'www.example.com',
                    username='user',
                    password='password',
                    cnopts=options) as conn:
        conn.get_d('remote/filedir', 'c:/local/output')
```

Comment: Nice. I've linked this from my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586224/connecting-to-an-sftp-server-using-pysftp-and-python-3-with-just-the-server-fing - Python 3 version