# Connecting to an SFTP server using pysftp and Python 3 with just the server fingerprint

Tags: python, ssh, pysftp

I'm in kind of a bizarre situation where I need to connect to an SFTP server for the first time but I can't seem to find a way to get access to the known host entry for the server.I can connect fine if I say:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection('host', username='me', password='pass', cnopts=cnopts):
```

But apparently that leaves you open to man in the middle attacks. So I attempt to connect with:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='config/known_host')
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

And I get all manner of error messages. The most recent one is:

> paramiko.hostkeys.InvalidHostKey

The problem is I have no host key because I'm connecting for the first time. I tried to get the key from other connections. I use WinSCP but it stores the key in a registry file and the format is different than known_host. I tried to get it with PuTTY using ssh-keyscan but the server won't even let me start a terminal session. We don't own the box and the hosting provider is unlikely to give us what we need.

Am I out of luck? Should I just go ahead and bypass checking the keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution can be found at [Python - pysftp / paramiko - Verify host key using its fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814823/python-pysftp-paramiko-verify-host-key-using-its-fingerprint) but I had to alter it a bit to use Python 3.

```
import hashlib as hl


def trim_fingerprint(fingerprint):
    #if fingerprint.startswith('ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 '):
        #return fingerprint[len('ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 '):]
    return fingerprint


def clean_fingerprint(fingerprint):
    #return trim_fingerprint(fingerprint).replace(':', '')
    return trim_fingerprint(fingerprint)

class FingerprintKey:

    def __init__(self, fingerprint):
        self.fingerprint = clean_fingerprint(fingerprint)

    def compare(self, other):
        if callable(getattr(other, "get_fingerprint", None)):
            return other.get_fingerprint() == self.fingerprint
        elif clean_fingerprint(other) == self.get_fingerprint():
            return True
        #elif hl.md5(other).digest().encode('hex') == self.fingerprint:
        #The line below is required for Python 3.  Above is Python 2.
        elif hl.md5(other).hexdigest() == self.fingerprint:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)

    def __contains__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.compare(other)

    def get_fingerprint(self):
        return self.fingerprint

    def get_name(self):
        return u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384'

    def asbytes(self):
         # Note: This returns itself.
         #   That way when comparisons are done to asbytes return value,
         #   this class can handle the comparison.
        return self
```

I had to manually remove any ":" from the fingerprint because it just never worked allowing the script to do it.

Usage:

```
options = pysftp.CnOpts()
options.hostkeys.clear()
options.hostkeys.add('www.sample.com', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 ', AuthOnFingerPrint.FingerprintKey(serverkey))
```

Where serverkey is the finger print.