# How to configure Python pysftp/paramiko connection with specific HostkeyAlgorithms

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I need to automate transferring of a file from one server to a client's SFTP server. I've done this hundreds of time using Python's pysftp package. However, on this occasion, there's a `HostkeyAlgorithm` that I need to set. I've read through Paramiko's doc since pysftp seems lacking of this option entirely and is built on Paramiko. But I honestly don't know what to do (I don't get to play with networking things often). I've been sending manually through bash with the following:

```
sftp -o HostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss user@host.com
```

I've tried the following in Python to no success:

```
import paramiko

_host='somehostname.com'
_user='thisguy'
_pass='you_get_the_idea'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy())
client.connect(_host, 22, _user, _pass)
```

This returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 424, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 714, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

So I guess the question is where/how do I add the `-o HostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss` when setting up my Paramiko connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paramiko will use host key algorithm matching a host key that you configure for your session.

You do not specify any host key, instead you blindly accept all host keys (`MissingHostKeyPolicy`), what is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

For a correct (and secure) approach, see:

- [Python - pysftp / paramiko - Verify host key using its fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46814823/850848)
- [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)

---

Though, I actually do not understand, why do you want to set "HostkeyAlgorithms", if you do not even verify the host key due to `MissingHostKeyPolicy`? – The *"Authentication failed"* error is for sure not related to host key.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response and the link. I didn't like the way the MissingHostKeyPolicy bit looked either but it kept popping up in everything I was seeing when Googling so I tried it. Good to know not to use it due to the security issues. The link you posted is very helpful.