# SFTP connection in Python, using a RSA-SSH 256 public key

Tags: python, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to log into an SFTP site in order to pull some data. I have seen code that references a fingerprint in MD5 format (example - `52:14:a4:33:71:0a:b9:46:25:73:a0:96:94:b3:3b:03`), but the key that i need to send is in a different format (I think SSH-256). When I generate a script from WinSCP to show the login info along with the RSA fingerprint I get the below:

```
sftp://login:password;fingerprint=ssh-rsa-ZnGWcuKoRO0Kv4uDjkdhOLHlnz9PSYfx04oGp9sE3d3=@ftp.address.com/
```

I've modified the actual key so it's just fictional in the post.

Can anyone please help with the Python package/code I would need to pass this type of fingerprint?

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578) - No one prevents you from getting the key in whatever format you might want. Actually with Paramiko/pysftp you typically verify the key using a full public key, not using any format of a fingerprint.

Comment: I guess to put it another way, how can i take the information WinSCP generates about my ftp connection details, and use it in Python to connect via sftp?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear. I do not understand, why you want to use information from WinSCP for your Python code.

But if you insist: There is an existing question about verifying host key in pysftp/Paramiko using MD5 fingerprint:

- [Python - pysftp / paramiko - Verify host key using its fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46814823/850848)

*(I assume it's the question you refer to in your post)*

In the `AutoAddPolicy` implementation from my answer to that question, you can replace `key.get_fingerprint()` with `sha256(key.asbytes()).digest()` to get SHA-256 fingerprint instead of MD5. You will need to import `sha56` from [`hashlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).

---

But I thing you should just follow standard Paramiko/pysftp host key verification instead, as for example shown in:

- [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)
- [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)