# No hostkey for host 192.168.50.35 found

Tags: python

I tried to connect my server using `pysftp`. But getting this error
`No hostkey for host 192.168.50.35 found`:

***.py**

```
import pysftp
srv = pysftp.Connection(host='192.168.50.35',username='myname',password='mypassword')
srv.close()
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Maybe one of the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp maybe of use? Also the ip does not respond to my ping.

Comment: @pinegulf Oh, really? Doesn't it? No surprise for a 192.168.* IP address.

Comment: @glglgl, Its an example, i tried with server IP but result was same.