# "No hostkey for host ***** found" when connecting to SFTP server with pysftp using private key

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

So I am having many issues connecting to a remote server via SFTP. I have tried the normal way like below.

```
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host='Host',username='username',password='passwd',private_key=".ppk")
```

Which did not work. I got the following error:

> SSHException: No hostkey for host ***** found.

I then tried the following:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
s = pysftp.Connection(host='host', username='user', password='password', cnopts=cnopts)
```

Which also did not work. I got the following error:

> BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', ['publickey']) (allowed_types=['publickey'])

Also when I run the following:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("host",username = "username",password = "password")
ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
```

I get the same error:

> BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', ['publickey']) (allowed_types=['publickey'])

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your are confusing a private key used for authentication and a host key used to verify an identify of a server. Both need to be taken care of, while all your code attempts take care of one of them only. See *my* article on [SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) to understand the difference between the two kinds of keys involved in SSH.

So this should "work":

```
# Accept any host key (still wrong see below)
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
# And authenticate with a private key
sftp = pysftp.Connection(
    host='Host', username='user', password='passwd', private_key=".ppk",
    cnopts=cnopts)
```

But this code will actually blindly accept any host key (`cnopts.hostkeys = None`), what is a security flaw. For a correct approach, see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `host` you are connecting is not available. This usually happens when the host-name is not accessible because of firewall rules (or typo on host).
I'd recommend first checking if you can sftp from the (unix) terminal

```
> sftp username@host
```

If you get prompted for password or get logged in, you are able to connect to that host from that machine

If not try checking if that host is available using `netcat` on port 22, you'd get timeout or broken pipe if host is not available

```
>nc -v host 22
```

I recommend debugging the `pysftp` or `paramiko` packages only after that.

Also, if you are authenticating using a private key, you do not need to use the password.