# "No hostkey for ... found" in pysftp code even though cnopts.hostkeys is set to None

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

**Background**

To SFTP across to another server I use the following command in the UNIX command line:

```
sftp -i /some_dir/another_dir/key -oPort=12345 user@12.123.456.789
```

**What I want to achieve**

I want to convert this to command to be used with [`PySFTP`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-secure-ftp-module).

**What I have tried**

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

# source: https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.7/pysftp.html
srv = pysftp.Connection("user@12.123.456.789", port="12345",  
                         private_key_pass="/some_dir/another_dir/key")
```

**Errors encountered**

```
File "./aws_sql_dumper.py", line 14, in <module>
    srv = pysftp.Connection("user@12.123.456.789", port="12345",  private_key_pass="/some_dir/another_dir/key")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host user@12.123.456.789 found.
Exception ignored in: <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7f6067c7ea20>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 784, in close
    if self._sftp_live:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'
```

**Research done**

I've read up on the following:

- [pysftp 0.2.9 breaks builds](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/issues/97/pysftp-029-breaks-builds)
- [Welcome to pysftp’s documentation!](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/)
- [Stuck in a pysftp Dilemma - Needing Help](https://pythonprogramming.net/community/281/Stuck%20in%20a%20pysftp%20Dilemma%20-%20Needing%20Help/)
- [S/O - Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp)

**Question**

I think I am doing something fundamental wrong. How can I adopt the SFTP command used in UNIX command line to be accepted/interpretted by `pysftp`?

---

**Changes**

I changed a few things around

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.load('/home/some_dir/.ssh/known_hosts')

# source: https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.7/pysftp.html
srv = pysftp.Connection("user@12.123.456.789", port="12345",  
                         private_key="/some_dir/another_dir/key", cnopts=cnopts)
```

**Output after change**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./aws_sql_dumper.py", line 17, in <module>
    srv = pysftp.Connection("user@12.123.456.789", port="12345",  private_key="/some_dir/another_dir/key", cnopts=cnopts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host user@12.123.456.789" found.
Exception ignored in: <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x7f8120dc6438>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 784, in close
    if self._sftp_live:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, converting the following SFTP command put into the terminal:

```
sftp -i /some_dir/another_dir/key -oPort=12345 user@12.123.456.789
```

can be translated* into:

```
paramiko.SSHClient().connect(hostname='12.123.456.789', username='user', port=12345,
                             key_filename='/some_dir/another_dir/key')
```

The whole condensed code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import paramiko

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
    client.connect(hostname='12.123.456.789', username='user', port=12345, 
                   key_filename='/some_dir/another_dir/key')

    # -------------------------- [ just for testing ] --------------------------
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -la')   # THIS IS FOR TESTING
    print(stdout.read())                                    # AND PRINTING OUT

finally:
    client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never use the `cnopts` variable. You need to pass it to `cnopts` parameter of `Connection` class.

Once you resolve this, you will have a problem with the private key, as you pass it to `private_key_pass` parameter (*"private key passphrase"*) instead of to `private_key`.

```
srv = pysftp.Connection("user@12.123.456.789", port="12345",  
                         private_key="/some_dir/another_dir/key", cnopts=cnopts)
```

---

Though you should not do `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, as you lose security by doing so. The right solution is to verify the host key. Check [my answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848) for correct solutions.

Comment: I'm still having some difficulty (I've updated the question) I read your answer and did so, but still to no avail. What else should I be doing? Or is there an alternative simpler library you could recommend?

Comment: So what did you do exactly? How did you update the `known_hosts`? What does the `known_hosts` contains? Show us.

Comment: Is there a way I can bypass `known_hosts` (I've become so confused with the known hosts - the more I read the more confused I've become)  and just use the key (`/some_dir/another_dir/key`) and the user alongside  the IP address `user` [`@`] `12.123.456.789`

Comment: @3kstc What is `/some_dir/another_dir/key`? Actually your are probably confused :) As I assume that `key` is your key for authentication, what has nothing to do with host keys/known hosts. Read my article [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) - So if you actually put your *authentication key* to `known_hosts`, then it's clear why it does not match the *host key*.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue (Host key issue) and found a good solution. In am trying to connect from a windows box(source) to Linux box(Destination). In my windows machine we have already installed CYGWIN where i logged in and did the below

```
1. Logged in using my ID
2. Ran the command ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa
3. under my cygwin home dir (~/.ssh) folder was created with pub and private key.
4. Physically this folder would be in c:\cygwin\home\/.ssh
5. Copy this folder and paste in the c:\user\\.ssh (windows home dir)
6. also open the pub key in the folder and paste that in the destination server ~\.ssh\authroized_keys. This is for password less login.
```

After this pysftp was able to connect without password less. Host key would be detected without any issues

-Prasanna.K