# connecting to an SFTP server via python

Tags: python, server, python-requests, sftp, pysftp

I've been stack for a few days now. I'm wondering if anyone can help me with any suggestions on how to connect to the sFTP server below.
The python code I've tried is as follows:

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection(host ='https://api1.datasource.eex-group.com ', username = 'blablabla', password ='blablabla') as sftp:
    
    print ('Connected!')
```

When that didn't work, I tried this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api1.datasource.eex-group.com', auth=(' username', 'password'))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that you should be using an https address to connect to an stfp server. Try and remove the `https://`
Can you show the issue?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply! I'm getting the following error when i remove https://:SSHException: No hostkey for host api1.datasource.eex-group.com  found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   
with pysftp.Connection(host ='https://api1.datasource.eex-group.com ', username = 'blablabla', password ='blablabla', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:

print ('Connected!')
```

Else here are a few solutions to this problem:
["No hostkey for host ***** found" when connecting to SFTP server with pysftp using private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864260/no-hostkey-for-host-found-when-connecting-to-sftp-server-with-pysftp-usi)
[Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp)
["No hostkey for ... found" in pysftp code even though cnopts.hostkeys is set to None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155030/no-hostkey-for-found-in-pysftp-code-even-though-cnopts-hostkeys-is-set-to)

Comment: I think we are up to something here Daniel, just that this time I got a different error with the code you provided. It's as follows: gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed and ConnectionException: ('https://api1.datasource.eex-group.com ', 22). I googled the first error and added import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080) but it did me no good. Any more suggestions?