# secure ftp connection using python module pysftp

Tags: python, ssh, python-3.6, sftp, pysftp

I need to connect to secure FTP server from windows-7 machine. I have user credentials to login to the server and its working  when i secure ftp using winscp.

I have tried using the `pysftp.connection()` but its failing for `host_keys` loading.

import pysftp

try:
    sftp =  pysftp.Connection('zzz.yyy.com', username='usr_nm', password='xxxxx')
except Exception as err:
    print('sftp failed', str(err))

below is the error message...

sftp failed No hostkey for host zzz.yyy.com found.
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\ppp.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp)

Comment: Particularly see [my answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848#43389508). The most voted answer is wrong.