# File upload to SFTP using Python (pysftp) fails with "No such file"

Tags: python, file-upload, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to upload a CSV file to an SFTP server from my machine. I don't know why my code is not able to find the file. Need little help to identify the issue. Here's my code

```
import pysftp as sftp
def sftpExample():
    try:
        cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys = None
        s = sftp.Connection(host='abc.net', username='xyz', password='aaaaaaaaaaaa',cnopts=cnopts)

        remotepath = 'http://sftp.abc.net/uploads/'
        localpath = '/Users/ashish.verma/Desktop/Text.rtf'
        s.put(localpath,remotepath)

        s.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
sftpExample()
```

Connection to the SFTP server is successful, but I don't know why my code is not able to find the file on my local machine. Error message says:

> No such file

Answer (score 2):

The `remotepath` argument of pysftp [`Connection.put` method](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.put) is a **file path**. Not **directory URL**, let alone **HTTP** URL.

It should be like:

```
remotepath = '/uploads/Text.rtf'
s.put(localpath, remotepath)
```

---

Alternatively you can omit the argument, making pysftp upload the file to the current remote working directory under the original file name (taken from `localpath`):

```
s.cd('/uploads')
s.put(localpath)
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.