# Pysftp: operation timed out

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to connect to a server using the following script:

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None 

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="sftp://my_ip:my_port", 
                        username="alessandro", password="alessandro", port=2222,
                        cnopts=cnopts)
data = srv.listdir()
srv.close()

for i in data:
    print (i)
```

If I try to access via FileZilla or similar clients, with the same credentials, it works; even though it displays the following warning, concerning host key algorithm and fingerprint as:

[image]

however, the script does not run properly and reports the following error:

> SSHException: Unable to connect to sftp://my_ip:my_port: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Even if I try with *host = my_ip* only. Additionally, if I do not set cnopts, it does not find the host key.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The `host` parameter of [`Connection` constructor](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection) is:

> The *Hostname* or *IP* of the remote machine.

Not an *URL*.

So it should be:

```
srv = pysftp.Connection(host="my_ip", 
                        username="alessandro", password="alessandro", port=2222,
                        cnopts=cnopts)
```

---

*Additionally, do not set the `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security.

For the correct solution, see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.