# Host key not found error with pysftp connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to push a file to an FTP server using the following code from a Python 3 course I am following. I know this question has been asked before, but other questions don't seem to have tried as many attempts as I have.

```
import pysftp as sftp
import paramiko
from base64 import decodebytes

def get_cnoopts():
    #keydata = b"""2048 SHA256:XpP32aA8DFDaJ46A3V7GEXk+wJldB3K7HHAFlD4pvQ4 root@DevTuts (RSA)"""
    keydata = b"""2048 SHA256:XpP32aA8DFDaJ46A3V7GEXk+wJldB3K7HHAFlD4pvQ4"""
    key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
    cnoopts = sftp.CnOpts()
    cnoopts.hostkeys.add("178.62.45.50", "ssh-rsa", key)

def push_file():
    s = sftp.Connection("198.63.45.20", username="root", password="sfewewetw", cnopts=get_cnoopts())
    local_path = "testme.txt"
    remote_path = "/home/testme.txt"

    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()

push_file()
```

I have changed sensitive data above to protect the innocent, so this code will never work for you as is.

I first tried without the `cnopts=get_cnoopts()` argument, and then I get the very explanatory error:

```
SSHException: No hostkey for host 178.62.45.50 found.
```

Then I found the code for `get_cnoopts` in an answer here on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43389508/8741), but now I have to find a key that doesn't throw an error on `decodebytes`.

Finding host keys with `ssh-keyscan` yields:

```
# 178.62.45.50:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
178.62.45.50 ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIHTaCuJ+5dzrHyHWr7GwD/c2x7cwL2IaEiXpI+ygd4Ma
# 178.62.45.50:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
178.62.45.50 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDGeglgB51BVCuh6wVZFrp2iyBEOFpaLDiSobQT+41Nn39kSGEJXBUPJ+aJfLRZ2e4Eu2o+3DV4gKsG4IEnV10WpBQxAmuq4EQesO/wTQdfgregarteartyertyer5sJwKkyTvLxBLX3AplbS1zBrSTvMWnqqvNV8IaqcR43JOkdt8frtm6dELalNpdTN4Vm/+VdRiFpzUIUj4lyVcnlttXXreE7p8qciRRfCFYA5OhsAvsSDxccv99dvHDYsrdomHZRbpYzel2QNSWLylEsnbRLDABY13n4xtELXC0Us8QyMjhF2x5l7fkm4RYjQmheNdkoN1Ot
# 178.62.45.50:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
178.62.45.50 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNretryreyrtZE8I2opSVi7R+2nlGMOs05s8j1NZfH3vIB7mL1ehfPbgp8Sjg8daQxQkm0U+NqWjCRE=
```

I tried all key lines, and the first gives me:

```
SSHException: No hostkey for host 178.62.45.50 found.
```

When I say I tried all *key lines* is that for each potential key given by `ssh-keyscan`, I have substituted each line in the output for my `keydata` variable value in my Python script.

Now I have tried using the entire string for `keydata`, and skipping the words from the beginning of the key string and both give me the same error. Using the second and third key strings I get the same error. The answer I examined also suggests using `pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='known_hosts')` where 'known_hosts' contains a server public key.

Then I tried another approach suggested in the same answer, as an alternative to `get_cnoopts`:

```
def get_cnoopts():
    cnoopts = sftp.CnOpts(knownhosts="""178.62.45.50 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDGeglgB51BVCuh6wVZFrp2iyBEOFpaLDiSobQT+41Nn39kSGEJXBUPJ+aJfLRZ2e4Eu2o+3DV4gKsG4IEnV10WpBQxAmuq4EQesO/wTQCXuUPw7LknIbIA3pFvJUxOa1K3xRm2TZgs9esJwKkyTvLxBLX3AplbS1zBrSTvMWnqqvNV8IaqcR43JOkdt8frtm6dELalNpdTN4Vm/+VdRiFpzUIUj4lyVcnlttXXreE7p8qciRRfCFYA5OhsAvsSDxccv99dvHDYsrdomHZRbpYzel2QNSWLylEsnbRLDABY13n4xtELXC0Us8QyMjhF2x5l7fkm4RYjQmheNdkoN1Ot""")
    return cnoopts
```

and I got the same error. Then I tried another suggestion, to use the `winSCP->Server and protocol information dialogue, which lists MD5 and SHA-256 keys nice and explicitly. I have tried both key strings, with and without prefixes like`ssh-ed25519 255`, with the same error.

I suspect either the course's code is out of date, or I'm introducing some sort of encoding problem with copy and pasting between a source and my Python code. What could be wrong here?

Comment: *"I tried all key lines"* – How example did you try them? Give us more details.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The output of `ssh-keyscan`, visible in the question, has 6 lines. Three begin with a `#` and are all the same: `# 178.62.45.50:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3`. The other 3 lines that begin with an IP address are what I called *key lines*, and I have assumed they either contain the key, as the last phrase on the line, or the whole line is a key. I have tried both

Comment: **How have you tried them?** Show us the code and/or what file did you modify and how.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl What code or info haven't I displayed or referenced?

Comment: You wrote that you *"tried all key lines"*, but you haven't shown us what did you do exactly to try them.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have edited the question to describe how I tried all *key lines*.

Comment: Sorry, but that's far from "exact" description. Show us your code. We need [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_cnoopts()` doesn't `return` anything, so `cnoopts=get_cnoopts()` will be the same as `cnoopts=`. Try adding `return cnoopts` to the end of your `get_cnoopts()` function:

```py
def get_cnoopts():
    keydata = b"""AAAA..."""
    key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
    cnoopts = sftp.CnOpts()
    cnoopts.hostkeys.add("178.62.45.50", "ssh-rsa", key)
    return cnoopts
```

I've been frustrated by pysftp's key handling myself - I only managed to get it to work by manually loading (like you do) the host's RSA key, after copy/pasting from the output of `ssh-keyscan`. But the key snippets you show in your code look incorrect: an ssh RSA key [should always begin with "AAAA"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5948) followed by a continuous stream of base64-encoded text (so no spaces, or hyphens). Try making these two changes and report back.