# Verify host key with pysftp against known_hosts file with custom port

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, pysftp

I'm trying to login in an SFTP server using `pysftp`.

This is the code I'm testing:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
# cnopts.hostkeys = None
host = 'data-nz.metservice.com'
username = 'my_user'
password = 'my_passwd'
ciphers = ['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc']
  
with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password,
                       port=9022, ciphers=ciphers, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
  
    sftp.listdir()
```

Note that:

1. The server uses a non-standard port
2. The server only uses the five listed ciphers to negotiate the connection, therefore this option is mandatory

This code fails because he host key cannot be found:

> SSHException: No hostkey for host data-nz.metservice.com found.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp), and I have successfully used the workaroud of setting `cnopts.hostkeys=None` (see commented out line in my code). But obviously I'd like to remove this security flaw. However I don't know how to cope this exception. I have logged in using plain `sftp` to make sure that the required line is added to my `known_hosts`. This action actually added two lines (whose content is not fully clear to me, as there is not explicit reference to the the URL, but anyway...), and now `sftp` does not complain:

```
|1|l+HfDGPUhea+8cUzCS+jq2HGcBg=|XMWhbkgujRtW1lJ4E93sTidUiCs= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC8N65MCdnbHjaEDxkZPPq1QO0RLwP3cdm9Gb9BAMS0mFH39d7/yHIerA6yFZRW27u3NClI7V1F3hDuheoCUomeF9Q9ioaeQ2dlX27hmGf611RpSfI/vGgnmipHYzzHsCIJi0LxuowCouKNw8g1v1e2VzsVWFPaq+cDeuUpDwpBKWnxQUWN7U9mzN1k0sDALimWOzhfQmXtCzPkHqERUcPpdU7/zWP8Xk9H7FQxgiPFa+EC5xuCzn01CcJppQ8VBqL9R6SNNP/d9ymQWh3cotXe6sj5gt2MdfbAUfxddQITW1rU+LSOkG21QPMq0VBDJwWf9RpqhnqcvusZIFVGyOsn
|1|uILdQCq4UAlxnruPlWnb7vwpWbc=|AOjbzHHXJ44ibhLVJJSGk++ep+U= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC8N65MCdnbHjaEDxkZPPq1QO0RLwP3cdm9Gb9BAMS0mFH39d7/yHIerA6yFZRW27u3NClI7V1F3hDuheoCUomeF9Q9ioaeQ2dlX27hmGf611RpSfI/vGgnmipHYzzHsCIJi0LxuowCouKNw8g1v1e2VzsVWFPaq+cDeuUpDwpBKWnxQUWN7U9mzN1k0sDALimWOzhfQmXtCzPkHqERUcPpdU7/zWP8Xk9H7FQxgiPFa+EC5xuCzn01CcJppQ8VBqL9R6SNNP/d9ymQWh3cotXe6sj5gt2MdfbAUfxddQITW1rU+LSOkG21QPMq0VBDJwWf9RpqhnqcvusZIFVGyOsn
```

But still the host key seems not to be acknowledged from Python. Any idea what is wrong with my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem  is that pysftp do not support custom ports when looking up the host key in the `known_hosts` file.

Add an entry like this:

```
data-nz.metservice.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC8N65MCdnbHjaEDxkZPPq1QO0RLwP3cdm9Gb9BAMS0mFH39d7/yHIerA6yFZRW27u3NClI7V1F3hDuheoCUomeF9Q9ioaeQ2dlX27hmGf611RpSfI/vGgnmipHYzzHsCIJi0LxuowCouKNw8g1v1e2VzsVWFPaq+cDeuUpDwpBKWnxQUWN7U9mzN1k0sDALimWOzhfQmXtCzPkHqERUcPpdU7/zWP8Xk9H7FQxgiPFa+EC5xuCzn01CcJppQ8VBqL9R6SNNP/d9ymQWh3cotXe6sj5gt2MdfbAUfxddQITW1rU+LSOkG21QPMq0VBDJwWf9RpqhnqcvusZIFVGyOsn
```

---

Or use Paramiko directly (pysftp is a wrapper around Paramiko), as Paramiko implements the host key lookup with custom port correctly.

---

Some background: The codes at the beginning of your original `known_hosts` are hashed `host[:port]` identifiers. Pysftp does not use port when looking up the entry, so it does not find the correct one. If you add fake (hashed or not) entry without the custom port, pysftp will be able to find it.