# gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known | pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I was trying to make a connection to a Free Public SFTP Server that I found [here](https://www.sftp.net/public-online-sftp-servers) using pysftp.

I tried:

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None 


sftp = pysftp.Connection('demo.wftpserver.com:2222', username='demo-user', password='demo-user', cnopts=cnopts)
sftp.close()
```

However it yields:

`ConnectionException: ('demo.wftpserver.com:2222', 22)` and `gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Is this a workaround to this issue?

*Please Advise.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number goes to the `port` parameter of `Connection` constructor. The `host` parameter takes just a hostname.

```
sftp = pysftp.Connection(
    'demo.wftpserver.com', port=2222, username='demo-user', password='demo-user',
    cnopts=cnopts)
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.

Comment: Thanks! , Well aware of the warning too! :)