# Error: 'failed to load hostkey' in pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to copy files from SFTP server too local server (window) using python pysftp libraries.
I am authenticating sftp server with usrname & password and no SSH-Host keys.

My code is running and copying files to local directory but still getting warning message about HostKeys.

```
import pysftp
import sys
import csv
import json, os
from pysftp import known_hosts
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore',category=UserWarning)

myHostname = "exmaple.com"
myUsername = "user"
myPassword = "foo"

data = []
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

try:
    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, port=22, cnopts=cnopts ) as sftp:        
        print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
        #cnopts=cnopts

        # Define the file that you want to download from the remote directory
        remoteFilePath = '/rcv'

        os.chdir("gpgencrypted")

        file = sftp.get_d(remoteFilePath,'',preserve_mtime=True)
        print("File copied to mid-server successfully")
except ValueError:
    print("File Transfer was unsuccessful")
```

Here is warning error in output. I am setting None hostkey in code but still warning message is appearing

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 61
    warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\kiran.patil\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
Connection succesfully stablished ... 
None
```

Edit 1:
Added warning filter to skip UserWarning. Ideally host-key should be used but right now I dont have sftp host key but I definitely use host-key before we commit to production.

Comment: Looks like is  just a warning

Comment: how to suppress the warning ?

Comment: Try configuring warnings https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added warning filter to skip UserWarning. Ideally host-key should be used but right now I dont have sftp host key but I definitely use host-key before we commit to production

```
import pysftp
import sys
import csv
import json, os
from pysftp import known_hosts
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore',category=UserWarning)

myHostname = "example.coom"
myUsername = "useer"
myPassword = "foo"

data = []
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

try:
    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, port=22, cnopts=cnopts ) as sftp:        
        print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
        #cnopts=cnopts

        # Define the file that you want to download from the remote directory
        remoteFilePath = '/rcv'

        os.chdir("gpgencrypted")

        file = sftp.get_d(remoteFilePath,'',preserve_mtime=True)
        print("File copied to mid-server successfully")
except ValueError:
    print("File Transfer was unsuccessful")
```

Comment: *"I dont have sftp host key"* – what do you mean by that? Of course you do.

Comment: I found the key using putty but any idea how can I use file in code. I am running script on window server. Many other documentation reefers to linux based systems.

Comment: There's a link in my answer to the duplicate question: [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).