# SFTP download with pysftp put fails with "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, airflow, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to automate the transfer of files from an SFTP sever through Airflow, but I am running into a problem where I cannot save the files anywhere except to the root folder.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword,     private_key=".ppk",
 cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
     print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
     # Obtain structure of the remote directory '/var/www/vhosts'
     directory_structure = sftp.listdir_attr()
     #Download data
     for attr in directory_structure:
         if datetime.fromtimestamp(attr.st_mtime) >= datetime.strptime("2022-01-18", "%Y-%m-%d"):
             sftp.put(attr.filename,"/volume1/homes/[myuser]/Recordings/{a}".format(a=attr.filename))
```

When I run this DAG, I get the following error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Paramiko [`SFTPClient.put`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) is for *upload*.

If you want to *download*, you have to use [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get):

```
sftp.get(attr.filename,"/volume1/homes/[myuser]/Recordings/{a}".format(a=attr.filename))
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.