# Python pysftp fails with "[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"

Tags: python, windows, upload, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to upload a file to Adobe Stock using SFTP in Python 3.8. Here are the instructions on their website: https://helpx.adobe.com/stock/how-to/upload-video-to-adobe-stock.html.

Here's my Python code:

```
import pysftp

pw = r'mypassword'
id = r'myid'
host = r'sftp://sftp.contributor.adobestock.com'
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=id, password=pw, log="./pysftp.log", port=22, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
  sftp.put(r'E:\myfile.mp4')
```

The PW and ID are just copied and pasted from Adobe Stock exactly as they provide it to me. Unfortunately, this does not work. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\Joe\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
  warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 176, in _start_transport
    self._transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 433, in __init__
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Downloads\test adobe sftp cl.py", line 36, in <module>
    with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=id, password=pw, log="./pysftp.log", port=22, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._start_transport(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 183, in _start_transport
    raise ConnectionException(host, port)
pysftp.exceptions.ConnectionException: ('sftp://sftp.contributor.adobestock.com', 22)
```

What do I need to change in order to get this to work? I would like to upload to Adobe Stock using SFTP in Python but I can't quite figure out what is wrong. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The `host` parameter of pysftp [`Connection` constructor](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection) is:

> The *Hostname* or *IP* of the remote machine.

Not an *URL*.

So it should be:

```
host = r'sftp.contributor.adobestock.com'
```

---

*Additionally, do not set the `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security.

For the correct solution, see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.