# pysftp connection - No Host Keys Found

Tags: python-3.x, pysftp

I am working on the following  python code to download files using pysftp

```
import pysftp

host = 'xxx.yyy.solutions'
port = 22
username = 'Abc.xyz'
password= '1234_abcd$'
cnopts=pysftp.CnOpts()

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='known_hosts')
conn = pysftp.Connection(host=host,username=username, password=password,cnopts=cnopts)
```

But the above code generates an exception

> pysftp.exceptions.HostKeysException: No Host Keys Found

The ssh-keyscan 'xxx.yyy.solutions' command shows the output as

[image: ssh-keyscan out put]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having trouble with this create a folder in your user called ".ssh" and then create a file named "known_hosts" in that folder. Afterward, run the below code to create a host key for your site.

```
import pysftp

Hostname = "your_hostname"
Username = 'your_username'
Password = "your_password"
Port = 22

host = Hostname

# Loads .ssh/known_hosts    
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()

hostkeys = None

if cnopts.hostkeys.lookup(host) == None:
    print("New host - will accept any host key")
    # Backup loaded .ssh/known_hosts file
    hostkeys = cnopts.hostkeys
    # And do not verify host key of the new host
    cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(Hostname, username=Username, password=Password, port=Port, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    if hostkeys != None:
        print("Connected to new host, caching its hostkey")
        hostkeys.add(
            host, sftp.remote_server_key.get_name(), 
                sftp.remote_server_key)
        hostkeys.save(pysftp.helpers.known_hosts())
```

Finally, add the below code creating the connection object, the issue will be resolved and is better than disabling cynopts

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.load('C:/Users/_your_user_/.ssh/known_hosts')
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it but this is the solution that I found after months of digging.

Comment: What the *"file named "local_host""* good for? You never use it in your code. + Why don't you simply use `ssh-keyscan`? See [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).

Comment: I tried that approach but couldn't get it to work, I also corrected the typo, I meant known_hosts. For some reason, the code would error out if there wasn't a file in that folder already named "known_hosts", why idk.

Comment: You should not use pysftp in the first place. It's abandoned project. And yes, it has known issues with `known_hosts` among others. My answer to the linked question says that too. And that still does not explain why you don't use `ssh-keyscan`.

Comment: *I tried that approach but couldn't get it to work*....What I posted worked for me; is it the best solution? Let me reiterate the last sentence in my original comment: "I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it but this is the solution that I found after months of digging."

Comment: The best way is not to use pysftp. Use Paramiko instead.

Comment: .....ok you were right...use paramiko....