# Setting up test connection to server using pysftp

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pysftp, libssl

I'am trying to establish a test connection to an sftp server. (as demonstrated in [Python Pysftp Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092850/python-pysftp-error/38355117#38355117)). I got the key from the server by establishing a first connection to the server via terminal. That worked flawlessly. However if I run the python script:

```
import pysftp 
sftp = pysftp.Connection('test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password') 
data = s.listdir() 
sftp.close() 
for i in data: 
    print(i)
```

I get the following error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/Documents/Python
> Projects/ftp_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
>     sftp = pysftp.Connection('test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password')   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp-0.2.9-py3.4.egg/pysftp/__init__.py",
> line 116, in __init__
>     self._cnopts = cnopts or CnOpts()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pysftp-0.2.9-py3.4.egg/pysftp/__init__.py",
> line 54, in __init__
>     self.hostkeys.load(knownhosts)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko-2.1.2-py3.4.egg/paramiko/hostkeys.py",
> line 101, in load
>     e = HostKeyEntry.from_line(line, lineno)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko-2.1.2-py3.4.egg/paramiko/hostkeys.py",
> line 335, in from_line
>     key = ECDSAKey(data=decodebytes(key), validate_point=False)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko-2.1.2-py3.4.egg/paramiko/ecdsakey.py",
> line 138, in __init__
>     self.verifying_key = numbers.public_key(backend=default_backend())   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography-1.8.1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py",
> line 74, in default_backend
>     _default_backend = MultiBackend(_available_backends())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography-1.8.1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py",
> line 31, in _available_backends
>     "cryptography.backends"   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography-1.8.1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py",
> line 30, in <listcomp>
>     for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
>     ['__name__'])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography-1.8.1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py",
> line 7, in <module>
>     from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography-1.8.1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 49, in <module>
>     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cryptography-1.8.1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 12, in <module>
>     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory
```

I checked the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf file to have a look at the search path which is /usr/local/lib. In said path I can find the libssl.so.1.1 file. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to interpret the error message or knows where I went wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind me bothering you. The solution was easy:
Turns out I had to run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

As has been previously suggested in [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s#21173918)